# jquery source tag both in header and in body doesn't match

Tags: jquery, html, css

So i need two parts of jquery, one for my dropdown and one for my 'back to top" link.

edit: i'll post the whole page like it is now (i'll leave some html out)

so now the dorpdown menu works but the back to top doesn't)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--
    Strongly Typed 1.1 by HTML5 UP
    html5up.net | @n33co
    Free for personal and commercial use under the CCA 3.0 license (html5up.net/license)
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Kinderen en jongeren</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1040" />
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amaranth:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!--[if lte IE 9]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!--[if IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//css/font/font-awesome-ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
        <!--[if IE 7]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//css/font/font-awesome-ie7.min.css">
<![endif]-->

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/config.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         // Show or hide the sticky footer button
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                $('.go-top').fadeIn(200);
            } 
            else {
                $('.go-top').fadeOut(200);
            }
        });

        // Animate the scroll to top
        $('.go-top').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 300);
        });
    });
</script>


        <noscript>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel-noscript.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-desktop.css" />
        </noscript>
    </head>
    <body class="no-sidebar">
    <a id="top"></a>
<p> here is the html </p>





<div><a href="#" class="go-top">Go Top</a></div>




    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So when you tried adding noconflict did you use `jQuery` instead of `$` ?

Comment: If you don't need multiple versions of `jQuery`, you don't need to load the library more than once and use `noConflict`. Leave just the first load at the top, and add your external `script` files after that.

Comment: Seeing your page as a whole now, I can't see anything that would make something stop working. You have a single `jQuery` library loaded, followed by some external `JS` libraries and your piece of `script`. Check your browser console for errors.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because it's not pertinent anymore.